# Add a pay order button on WooCommerce My account view order for pending orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, orders

How create "pay for this order" button when order status is `pending` to be displayed on the my account page when viewing an order

The link structure is as follows:

`https://url.com/checkout/order-pay/XXXXX/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_XXXXXXXXXXXX`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'order_pay_button' );
function order_pay_button( $order_id ){
// Get an instance of the `WC_Order` Object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the order number
$order_number  = $order->get_order_number();

    
// Get the order status name
$status_name  = wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );

// Get the order key
 $test_order_key = $order->get_order_key();
 
   
// Display the order status 
echo '<div>' . __("Order Status:") . ' ' . $status_name . '</div>';



if ($status_name == "pending") {
   
     echo '
<a href="https://url.com/checkout/order-pay/'.''.$order_number.''.'/?pay_for_order=true&key='.''.$test_order_key.''.'">
<button type="submit" class="button alt" id="place_order">Pay for this order</button></a>';
   
} 


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following simplified code version, that will display a pay order button for pending orders:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'order_pay_button' );
function order_pay_button( $order_id ){
    // Get an instance of the `WC_Order` Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->get_status() == "pending" ) {
        printf(
            '<a class="woocommerce-button button pay" href="%s/order-pay/%s/?pay_for_order=true&key=%s">%s</a>',
            wc_get_checkout_url(), $order_id, $order->get_order_key(), __("Pay for this order", "woocommerce")
        );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.